# htaccess - Rewrite query without equal sign

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

so I have **two** redirects below. The first one with only variable **$id** is working and the second one with variables **$id** and **$newvariable** is not. My question is, since **$id** can be equal to any number, yet **$newvariable** isn't equal to anything, how do I set **$newvariable** as a redirect without any equal sign?

**Working query for just $id (which can be equal to any number)**

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^file\.php$ /directory/%1? [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^directory/(\d+)/?$ /directory/file.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

**My BROKEN query I'm trying to figure out with parameters $ID (which can be any number like above) AND $newvariable (which isn't equal to anything)**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/file\.php\?id=(\d+)&newvariable=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /directory/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^directory/(\d+)/(.*)/?$ /directory/file.php?id=$1&newvariable=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This is how the current URL is formatted **before** rewrites. As you can see, **$newvariable** isn't equal to anything in the URL:

```
http://ipaddress/directory/file.php?id=47&newvariable
```

My goal is to make this redirect work as follows, **after** rewrites:

```
http://ipaddress/directory/47/newvariable
```

I would appreciate any help with this! Thank you!

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file located? Your rules are not consistent with the URL you are trying to match. Is your URL `/directory/file.php?id=47&newvariable` or `/file.php?id=47&newvariable` (as "some" of your rules imply)?

Comment: So, `newvariable` is itself the value? Although, confusingly, you hardcoded this in the first rule (of the second block), but made it variable in the second?

Comment: What are the criteria for `newvariable`?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/file\.php\?id=(\d+)&newvariable=(\S+)\s [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ /directory/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
> RewriteRule ^directory/(\d+)/(.*)/?$ /directory/file.php?id=$1&newvariable=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
> ```
>
> `http://ipaddress/directory/file.php?id=47&newvariable`
> `http://ipaddress/directory/47/newvariable`

If `newvariable` is simply a *flag* (with no value) in the query string, then why are you checking for a non-empty value in the condition (ie. `newvariable=(\S+)`) and not just `(\S+)`? Likewise, why are you assigning a value to the `newvariable` parameter in the *substitution* string (ie. `&newvariable=$2`) and not just `&$2`?

However, the *condition* that checks against `THE_REQUEST` won't match the URL-path either, since you are matching against `/file.php`, whereas the URL-path you are seemingly trying to match is `/directory/file.php`?

Something like this may be closer to what you are trying to do:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/directory/file\.php\?id=(\d+)&(\w+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /directory/%1/%2 [QSD,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^directory/(\d+)/(\w+)/?$ /directory/file.php?id=$1&$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This needs to go *before* your first rule block since your first rule is matching too match and will otherwise capture the request and end up removing `newvariable` (see below).

I've restricted `newvariable` to the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_` (as denoted by the `\w` shorthand character class). `\S` arguably matches too much.

I've allowed an optional trailing slash on the "pretty" URL `/directory/47/newvariable/`, as you had on your directive. However, this is not present on your example URL and the preceding redirect does not add it, so it should be omitted if not required. (It potentially creates a duplicate content issue.)

NB: You are presumably already linking to URLs of the form `/directory/47/newvariable` internally?

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+) [NC]
> RewriteRule ^file\.php$ /directory/%1? [R=301,L,NC]
> ```

The *condition* that matches the query string is matching too much. It will also match `id=47&newvariable` since your regex is not anchored. If you are checking for `id=47` only then anchor the regex. For example:

```
:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
:
```

The `NC` flag is likely superfluous, unless you are also expecting `iD`, `Id` or `ID`?!

This will naturally only match a query string consisting of `id=<number>`. In doing so, you avoid the conflict and the order of these two rules is not so critical anymore.